# Mata Ka Jagrata Tradition (Mata Ki Chowki)

Tags: devi, durga, shakti, shaktism, kali

Is there some religious history or scriptural mention re all-night prayer of Devi w/ Mata Ka Jagrata ? Like how and where the tradition of it started ? I was reading that Kali Puja was started by King Krishnachandra and Ishvarchandra (with Kali veneration influenced by Krishnanand Agamvagish before that.) I think Mata Ka Jagrata is wonderful, just curious of the history behind it.

Comment: Pardon me but Bengal is located in Eastern India, not NE India

Comment: @AnubrataBit Pardon me too, I took the NE part out just now.

Comment: I think tantrikas practice 4 sandhya the 4th being medinight. So it must be related to this

Comment: @YOuwillnotknow Thx ! I didn’t know it was connected to the four sandhyas for tantriks. Jagran for Devi/Mata with the all-night puja seems more prevalent than for other deities.

Comment: Jagrans got nothing to do with any history. Devi herself states that one must fast, sing and dance her glories for whole night (same appears for Ekadashi vrata and Pradosha Vrata). But, alas now this has taken a new distorted shape in name of Jagrata.

Comment: @Chamundadas Oh ! Ok. I love the jagran for Devi with bhajans, puja, nritya, but had no idea where the tradition came from, which is why I posted the question. I googled several times before but couldn’t find info. Thx for clarifying :D